# Publish failed when using Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor if reference was not recognized, but build works

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

## The problem

I've upgraded my solution from asp.net core 2.0 web app to 2.1 and in one of my class libraries I'm using '[Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/sdk?view=aspnetcore-2.1)' SDK.

- Rebuilding the solution from VS works
- Publishing the web project from command line using 'dotnet publish' works
- **Publishing the web project from VS fails**. The error output suggests that some of my project in solution is not included when publishingthe library with razor views.
- When I remove `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` and use just 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' publishing from VS works.

## Solution projects:

- **MyProject.DataAccess.csproj** (netstandard2.0, nuget refereces Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1)
- **MyProject.Mail.csproj**  (netcoreapp2.1, Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor, references MyProject.DataAccess.csproj)
- **MyProject.Shared.csproj**  (netcoreapp2.1, Microsoft.NET.Sdk, references MyProject.DataAccess.csproj)
- **MyProject.Web.csproj** (netcoreapp2.1, Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web, references MyProject.Mail.csproj and MyProject.Shared.csproj, nuget reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.App);

The log file says:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more
>   details.    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.d__116.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---
>
> ===================

And in the output window is

```
Connecting to C:\Projects\tacs\MyProject\MyProject.Web\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\...
MyProject.Web -> C:\Projects\tacs\MyProject\MyProject.Web\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\MyProject.Web.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702,1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE;RELEASE;NETCOREAPP;NETCOREAPP2_1 /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.abstractions\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions.dll" / /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.extensions\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.razor\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.language\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.runtime\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.responsecaching.abstractions\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Abstractions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.abstractions\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.routing\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp\2.8.0\lib\netstandard1.3\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.codeanalysis.common\2.8.0\lib\netstandard1.3\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.codeanalysis.razor\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.abstractions\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.caching.abstractions\2.1.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll"  /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.win32.registry\4.5.0\ref\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\netstandard.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\newtonsoft.json.bson\1.0.1\lib\netstandard1.3\Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\newtonsoft.json\11.0.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\remotion.linq\2.2.0\lib\netstandard1.0\Remotion.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.AppContext.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Buffers.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Collections.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Collections.Immutable.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Collections.Specialized.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.ComponentModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Configuration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Console.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Data.Common.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.data.sqlclient\4.5.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Data.SqlClient.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Diagnostics.Process.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Drawing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Drawing.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Globalization.Calendars.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Globalization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Globalization.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.interactive.async\3.1.1\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Interactive.Async.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.IO.Compression.Brotli.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.IO.Compression.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.IO.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.IO.FileSystem.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.IO.Pipes.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Linq.Expressions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Linq.Parallel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Linq.Queryable.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Memory.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Net.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Net.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Net.HttpListener.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Net.Mail.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Net.NameResolution.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Net.Ping.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Net.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Net.Requests.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Net.Security.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Net.ServicePoint.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Net.Sockets.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Net.WebClient.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Net.WebProxy.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Net.WebSockets.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Numerics.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.ObjectModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Reflection.DispatchProxy.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Reflection.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Reflection.Emit.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Resources.Reader.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Resources.Writer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe\4.5.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Runtime.Handles.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Runtime.Loader.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.security.accesscontrol\4.5.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Security.AccessControl.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Security.Claims.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.security.cryptography.xml\4.5.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Security.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.security.permissions\4.5.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Security.Permissions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Security.Principal.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.security.principal.windows\4.5.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Security.SecureString.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.ServiceProcess.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Text.Encoding.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.text.encodings.web\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Threading.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Threading.Tasks.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Threading.Thread.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Threading.Timer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Transactions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Transactions.Local.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.ValueTuple.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Web.HttpUtility.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Windows.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Xml.Serialization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Xml.XDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Xml.XPath.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\WindowsBase.dll" /debug- /debug:portable /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\MyProject.Mail.dll /ruleset:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset" /target:library /warnaserror- /utf8output /deterministic+ /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.codeanalysis.analyzers\1.1.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.dll" /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.codeanalysis.analyzers\1.1.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.dll" /analyzer:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.analyzers\2.1.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers.dll" EmailDefaults.cs EmailOptions.cs MailSender.cs NotificationService.cs RazorViewToStringRenderer.cs "C:\Users\daniel.turan\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\MyProject.Mail.RazorAssemblyInfo.cs obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\MyProject.Mail.AssemblyInfo.cs /warnaserror+:NU1605
NotificationService.cs(15,12): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'DataAccess' does not exist in the namespace 'MyProject' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
NotificationService.cs(16,12): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'DataAccess' does not exist in the namespace 'MyProject' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug. Fix should be available in the upcoming SDK version 2.1.1. There are 3 things you can do right now:

1. You can install SDK 2.1.301 ([x64 Installer](https://dotnetfeed.blob.core.windows.net/orchestrated-release-2-1/20180605-09/final/assets/Sdk/2.1.301-preview-008906/dotnet-sdk-2.1.301-win-x64.exe), [x86 Installer](https://dotnetfeed.blob.core.windows.net/orchestrated-release-2-1/20180605-09/final/assets/Sdk/2.1.301-preview-008906/dotnet-sdk-2.1.301-win-x86.exe), [Version info](https://github.com/dotnet/versions/tree/master/build-info/dotnet/product/cli/release/2.1))
2. Or you can make the fix yourself for current 2.1.300 SDK, it's a one liner in **C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\build\netstandard2.0\Sdk.Razor.CurrentVersion.targets** and change line 460 from:

   ```
   DependsOnTargets="RazorCompile"
   ```

   to

   ```
   DependsOnTargets="ResolveRazorGenerateInputs"
   ```
3. Or keep using **dotnet publish**

Comment: I've upgraded the SDK (and installed lated VS update (15.7.4) and now the app won't start in azure app service: Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/myapp' with physical root 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\mypp.dll' failed to start process with commandline 'dotnet ', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 80008096.

Comment: Didn't know you publish to azure :). 2.1.301 is a preview release so it's unlikely updated runtime is deployed on Azure. If you uninstall preview SDK and go with Option 2 you should be fine.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use 2.1.301 just for building and use whatever runtime version is on azure?

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I have installed Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor 2.2.0

Open "Package Manager Console"
run follows query....

> Install-Package Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor -Version 2.2.0

Razor is a markup syntax for adding server-side logic to web pages. This package contains MSBuild support for Razor.